# Number of real or purely imaginary solution

Tags: complex-numbers

> What are the number of real or purely imaginary solution of the equation , $$z^3 +iz -1=0$$

In this I tried to substitute $z=x+iy$ and solve it, but it is getting too long, and the answer is also not coming

Comment: Hint:  If $z$ is real, can $z^3+iz-1$ be real?

Comment: @Lovsovs x and y are real numbers

Comment: @lulu no it cannot be real

Comment: Ok, so that's half your question answered, yes?

Comment: okay got it , the answer would be zero

Comment: By "purely imaginary" solutions, do you mean "z=x+iy" with $x \neq 0$ or "pure imaginary", i.e., $z=iy$ ?

Comment: $z (z^2+i)=1$ so it does not look like there can be real solutions. Is there a theorem you can use to claim that there are three complex solutions (FTA)?

Comment: @JeanMarie I think "purely imaginary" means $\;x=0\;,\;\;y\neq0\;$ .

Comment: pure imaginary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complex value is only equal to zero if both it's real and imaginary part are zero.

If $z$ is real then $z^3 - 1 + iz$ has an imaginary component of $z$. So the only possible solution would be $z = 0$, but this is not valid.

If $z$ is purely imaginary then it can be written as $ir$ for real $r$. Substituting $z = ir$ into the formula gives us:

$$(ir)^3 +i^2r - 1 = 0$$
$$- r - 1 -ir^3 = 0$$
$$-r -1 = 0 \wedge -r^3 = 0$$
$$r = -1 \wedge r = 0$$

This also forms a contradiction, thus there are no purely real or imaginary solutions.